# Is there a search algorithm for huge two-dimensional arrays?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, search, multidimensional-array

This is not a real-life question, it is just theory-crafting.

I have a big array which consists of elements like `[1,140,245,123443]`, all
integer or floats with low selectivity, and the number of unique values is ten
times less than the size of the array. B*tree indexing is not good in this case.

I also tried to implement bitmap indexing, but in Ruby, binary operations are not so fast.

Are there any good algorithms for searching two-dimensional arrays of fixed size vectors?

And, the main question is, how do I convert the vector in value, where the conversion function has to be monotonic, so I can apply range queries such as:

```
(v[0]<10, v[2]>100, v[3]=32, 0.67*10^-8<v[4]<1.2154241410*10^-6)
```

the only idea i have is to create separate sorted indexes for each component of vector...binary search then and merge...but it is a bad idea because in the worst case scenario it will require O(N*N) operations...

Comment: Oh, you want to find a row who's elements match a series of criteria?  Is that it?

Comment: yep, and i want to do that on ruby)

Comment: You can always add some C to your Ruby :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each "column" is vaguely evenly distributed in a known range, you could keep track of a series of buckets for each column, and a list of rows that satisfy the bucket.  The number of buckets for each column can be the same, or different, it's totally arbitrary.   More buckets is faster, but takes *slightly* more memory.

```
my table:
range:    {1to10} {1to4m}    {-2mto2m}
row1:     {7      3427438335 420645075}
row2:     {5      3862506151 -1555396554}
row3:     {1      2793453667 -1743457796}

buckets for column 1:
bucket{1-3} : row3
bucket{4-6} : row2
bucket{7-10} : row1

buckets for column 2:
bucket{1-2m} : 
bucket{2m-4m} : row1, row2, row4

buckets for column 3:
bucket{-2m--1m} : row2, row3
bucket{-1m-0} : 
bucket{0-1m} : 
bucket{1m-2m} : row1
```

Then, given a series of criteria: `{v[0]<=5, v[2]>3*10^10}`, we pull out the *buckets* that match that criteria:

```
 column 1:
v[0]<=5 matches buckets {1-3} and {4-6}, which is rows 2 and 3.
 column 2:
v[2]>3*10^10} matches buckets {2m-4m} and {4-6}, which is rows 1, 2 and 3.
 column 3:
"" matches all , which is rows 1, 2 and 3.
```

Now we know that the row(s) we're looking for meet all three criteria, so we list all the rows that are in the buckets that matched all the criteria, in this case, rows 2 and 3.  At this point, the number of rows remaining will be small even for *massive* amounts of data, depending on the granularity of your buckets.  You simply check each of the rows that is left at this point to see if they match.  In this sample we see that row 2 matches, but row 3 doesn't.

This algorithm is *technically* O(n), but in practice, if you have large numbers of small buckets, this algorithm can be *very* fast.

Comment: I don't think that it is a O(N) alg. For  example how many operations do u need then u have find common elements in 2 Nsize arrays(worst case scenario max range queries) i think N*N...

Comment: I dont understand what your saying.  When I say it's O(N),, I meant N is the number of rows, and I'm ignoring the number of columns.  If M is the number of columns, the algorithm is O(N*M), either way, it's the same algorithmic complexity as a linear search.

Comment: You said that "Now we know that the row(s) we're looking for meet all three criteria"...sot we have 3 arrays of rows ids and we have to find their intersection. Intersection of 2 unordered arrays required size_of_first_array * size_of_first_array operations, so in the worst case scenario it will require N*N operations...And i don't think that buckets is good idea, it is better to use uniq values as keys and row ids as value.

Comment: @YuriBarbashov: oh, right, good observation.  Finding the intersection is O(N^M), but because of the buckets, it's O((N/P)^M) (where N is the number of rows, P the number of buckets, and M the number of columns.  I'm not sure what you said about buckets.  Each "bucket" is merely a vector of row pointers, and so doesn't take much space.

Comment: Finding the intersection is O(M*N^2). I think it is better to store indexes like {1 => [1,434,55], 3 => [234,555,6643] ...123 => [34,533]} for queries like v[0] == 1, and not bad for range queries also

Answer (score 0):

Using an index :)

The basic idea is to turn the 2 dimensional array into a 1 dimensional sorted array(while keeping the original position) and apply binary search on the later.

This method works for any n dimensional array and is used widely by databases which can be seen as a n dimensional array with variable lengths.

Comment: yes, and as i said, the index array is a 1 dimensional sorted array :)

Comment: then, how can you index that kind of data?

Comment: simple data structure: value => list of positions in the original array, can be even a map.

Comment: the question is more about conversion of vector into value...because i need to find all array elements by range query, for example 0.67 * 10^-8 < v[4] < 1.2154241410*10^-6

Comment: can you provide an example. Cause i don't see why you can't do that using the index.

Comment: 1) what value does correspond to a vector [1,234,23,24234,125.45]? 2) for example i need all vectors which have v[0] < 10, v[2] >100, v[3] = 32, 143.2254 > v[4] > 12.14...what values do i have to search for in index table?  the only idea i have is to create separate sorted indexes for each component of vector...binary search and merge...

Comment: Hmm, yes seperate sorted indexes seems to be the generic idea. Unless there is a patter or a specificity on your values.